# How to use ReduceByKey on multiple key in a Scala Spark Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, avro

I'm relatively new to spark and I'm trying to group data by multiple keys at the same time.

I have some data that I map so it ends up looking like this:

((K1,K2,K3),(V1,V2))

My goal is to group by (K1,K2,K3) and respectively sum V1 and V2 to end up with:

((K1,K2,K3), (SUM(V1),SUM(V2))

Here is the code I have so far:

```
val filepath  = "file.avro"
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)            
val data = sqlContext.read.avro(filepath)
val dataRDD = data.rdd

val mappedDataRDD = dataRDD.map{
   case (v, w, x, y, z) => ((v,w,x), (y, z))
}.reduceByKey((x,y)=> ???)
```

So I'm looking for how to reduceByKey so I can group by the (v,w,x) keys and sum the y and z.

Comment: `???` = `(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for and should use is `aggregateByKey`.

This method takes two parameter groups. The first parameter group takes the starting value of accumulator. The second parameter group takes two functions,

1. A function which accumulates things into accumulator.
2. A functions which combines two accumulators.

Now you can use it as follows,

```
val (accZeroY, accZeroZ): (Long, Long) = (0, 0) 

val mappedDataRDD = dataRDD
  .map({
    case (v, w, x, y, z) => ((v,w,x), (y, z))
  })
  .aggregateByKey((accZeroY, accZeroZ))(
    { case ((accY, accZ), (y, z)) =>  (accY + y, accZ + z) }
    { case ((accY1, accZ1), (accY2, accZ2)) => (accY1 + accY2, accZ1 + accZ2) }
  )
```

As you should have observed that both the functions in the second parameter group are actually same in this case. Which is possible only in the cases when the `type of the needed accumulation` is same as the type of value in `key-value-RDD` or `PairRDD`.

In such cases you can also use `reduceByKey` which you can think of as an `aggregateByKey` with the same function passed as both function parameters,

```
val mappedDataRDD = dataRDD
  .map({
    case (v, w, x, y, z) => ((v,w,x), (y, z))
  })
  .reduceByKey(
    { case ((accY, accZ), (y, z)) =>  (accY + y, accZ + z) }
  )
```

But in my opinion, you `should NOT` use `reduceBykey`. The reason that I suggested the use of `aggregateByKey` is because accumulation of values on large datasets can sometime produce a result which is outside the range of your type.

For example in your case, I suspect that your `(x, y)` is actually an `(Int, Int)` and you want to accumulate it using `(v, w, x)` as key. But whenever you are adding `Int` in large amount... remember that the result can end up bigger than what an `Int` can handle.

So... you will want the type of your accumulation to be something with bigger range that `(Int, Int)` like `(Long, Long)` and `reduceByKey` does not allow you to do that. And so... I will say that perhaps you are looking for and should use `aggregateByKey`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reduceByKey`, you just have to be careful of what you want. I simplified the example, but it exposes what you want.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  (1, 2, 1, 1, 1), 
  (1, 2, 1, 2, 2),   
  (1, 3, 2, 4, 4)))

rdd.map {
  case (k1, k2, k3, v1, v2) => ((k1, k2, k3), (v1, v2))
}.reduceByKey {
  // You receive two values which are actually tuples, so we treat them like that.
  case ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) => (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
}.collect()
//res0: Array[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] = Array(((1,2,1),(3,3)), ((1,3,2),(4,4)))
```

Comment: While this definitely works as per my comment, you probably want the right number of keys (OP has `(k1,k2,k3)`. :)

Comment: @Alec I considered so many keys unnecessary. However, it's not so hard to put them back.